# How to use Closed Graph Theorem here?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We say a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in a Hilbert space $H$ is Riesz-Fischer (RF) if the equation $\langle f,f_n\rangle = c_n$ has at least one solution $f \in H$ whenever $c = (c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^2$. Show that if $\{f_n\}$ is RF, then there exists $K$ such that for every $c \in \ell^2$, there is a solution $f$ (i.e. $\langle f,f_n\rangle = c_n$) satisfying $\|f\| \leq K \|c\|$.

Fix $c \in \ell^2$, then since $\{f_n\}$ is RF we can show that the solution $f$ must be unique and is necessarily contained in $\overline{\text{span}}\{f_n\}$. Define the operator $T:\ell^2 \rightarrow \overline{\text{span}}\{f_n\}$ such that $Tc = f$, where $f$ is the unique solution. I want to show that the graph of this operator is closed and this will imply boundedness by Closed Graph Theorem which completes the exercise. The only thing we know is that $T$ is injective. Assume that $c_n \rightarrow c$ and $Tc_n \rightarrow y$, then we need to show $Tc = y$. I am not too sure how to proceed however. I have seen some proof that are similar, for instance [here](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Eawgreen/files/notes/moment-riesz-equiv.pdf), but was not convinced with the proof.

Comment: Can you show that the $f_j$ are orthogonal, or how do you show uniqueness?

Comment: If $f,f' \in \overline{\text{span}}\{f_n\}$ with $c_n = \langle f,f_n\rangle = \langle f',f_n\rangle$, then for $\langle f-f',f_n\rangle = 0$ for all $n$. This implies $f=f'$ since the only vector that can be orthogonal to all $\{f_n\}$ is the zero vector.

Comment: Ah, I see. You mean unique solution in the span. Ok.

Comment: Sorry about that! I should have clarified a bit more...

Comment: Have you tried to consider $c=(0, \dots, 0,1,0, \dots).$ This gives you $f$ in the span that is orthogonal to all $f_j$ except one.

Comment: As $f$ is in the span, you get $f=k_f f_j$. But that would tell you that actually all the $f_j$ are orthogonal. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: This is Proposition 2 in Chapter 4 Section 2 of $\textit{An Introduction to Non-Harmonic Fourier Series}$ (2001) by Young. However, they leave this as an exercise there and have not gone through it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested above the closed graph theorem is an appropriate tool. Indeed, assume $c^{(k)}\to c$ in $\ell^2$ and $Tc^{(k)}\to y$ in $H.$ Thus
$$\langle y,f_n\rangle =\lim_k\langle Tc^{(k)},f_n\rangle =\lim_kc_n^{(k)}=c_n$$
Therefore $Tc=y.$